# How to set values in the select dropdown box?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner in php. This is my code for the select dropdown box. My problem is how can I input data using php coming from the database I created in mysql and check if the data selected is successfully inserted.

```
<select name = "txtroundcake">
                <option value="" >SELECT ONE</option>
                <option value=">Boiled Icing 6" without filling</option>
                <option>Boiled Icing 6" with filling</option>
                <option>Boiled Icing 9" without filling</option>
                <option>Boiled Icing 9" with filling</option>
                <option>Boiled Icing 12" without filling</option>
                <option>Boiled Icing 12" with filling</option>
                <option>Boiled Icing 14" without filling</option>
                <option>Boiled Icing 14" with filling</option>
                <option>Fondant 2 1/2" without filling</option>
                <option>Fondant 4" without filling</option>
                <option>Fondant 9" without filling</option>
                <option>Fondant 9" with filling</option>
                <option>Fondant 12" without filling</option>
                <option>Fondant 12" with filling</option>
                <option>Fondant 14" without filling</option>
```

The schema for my database is
productinfo(productid,name,price,categoryid,description,image)

Comment: that formatting is a mess. Well, is the user allowed to use check multiple options (I have very little knowledge in HTML)?

Comment: Do you want to add value Dynamically using php?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so i think this code should do what your wanting.
the code below will take whatever Choice they choose, and place it in the Name column of the table called productinfo

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
echo "
<form action='' method='post'>
<table>
<b>Select One:</b>
<select name='name = "txtroundcake"'>
<option value='Choice1'>label here</option>
<option value='Choice2'>label here</option>
<option value='Choice3'>label here</option>
<option value='Choice4'>label here</option>
<option value='Choice5'>label here</option>
<option value='Choice6'>label here</option>
<option value='Choice7'>label here</option>
<option value='Choice8'>label here</option>
</select>
</table>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Send'></form>
<b>Message Here</b>
";


$txtroundcake = SecurePost($_POST['txtroundcake']);
if ($Submit) {
if(!$txtroundcake) {
echo"Please include your name";
}
else {

mysql_query("INSERT INTO productinfo (name) VALUES ('$txtroundcake')");  
echo "<font color='green'><b>Submitted!</b></font>";
}
}
?>
```

The comment i left didnt format code properly, so here it is

to get the price from product info, and display it you would do something like this

```
$getItems = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productinfo WHERE name LIKE '%$q%'
ORDER BY productid DESC"); 
$gI = mysql_fetch_object($getItems); 

<b>".$gI->price." Price</b> 
<b>".$gI->name." Name</b> 
i havent tested it, but i think to put this in a dropdown box you would do
<option value='Choice1'>Name:".$gI->name."Price:".$gI->price."</option>
or if you wanted to display a price and the name
<option value='Choice1'>Name:".$gI->name."Price:".$gI->price."</option>
```

but i am not posotive, goodluck

Comment: I want to get the price from the productinfo table to insert it to each of the select options. And once each of the select options have values, I would insert it to my peritemorder(ordernum,transacnum,quantity,productid,comment,attachment).

Comment: ok ok, sooooooo you want the options to be items from the product table????

Comment: to get the price from product info, and display it you would do something like this 
$getItems = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productinfo WHERE name LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY productid DESC");
$gI = mysql_fetch_object($getItems);


<b>".$gI->price." Price</b>
<b>".$gI->name." Name</b>

but i am not sure how to put that into a dropdown box :( sorry
goodluck